# Compare post-IDs within WP_Query? (Less than / Greater than)

Tags: php, wp-query, posts-where

Can I use `WP_Query` to only query posts less than (or greater than) a given post ID?

```
$filtered_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'order' => $prev_next=='next' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    // ID <= $post->ID
);
```

I've been digging around in [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) with no luck.

I can of course do this conditionally within the loop, but it would be much cleaner if I could use `WP_Query` directly.

Comment: Make use of the `posts_clauses` or `posts_where` filter. Dozens of examples on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using something like this:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
  global $post, $prev_next;
  $the_ID = $post->ID;
  $where .= " AND wp_posts.ID ";
  $where .= $prev_next=='next' ? "< $the_ID" : "> $the_ID";
  return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$nextProjQuery = new WP_Query( $filtered_query_args );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```